# JS slider menu toggling issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Q&A sider menu that can be clicked to reveal the answer. When you click on each question the answer is revealed and the other answer closed. I would also like to be able to re-click on the active question to close the answer. I'd appreciate any help/advice anyone could offer?

Here's the JS I currently have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#question > li > a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#question li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#question li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
 });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a click handler for $('#question > li > a.active'). This would respond to clicks only on your active < a > tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the else statement:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#question > li > a').click(function(){

  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
  $('#question li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#question li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
else{
    $(this).slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('active');

}
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This closed the actual question rather than the answer. I changed the else statements to `$('#question li ul').slideUp();` and `$('#question li a').removeClass('active');` and that sorted it. Many thanks!!